# proof of concept for multiple clients in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

I have to implement a Proof of concept for multi client handling in JSF 2.0. How can multiple clients be handled in jsf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do not store request or session scoped data in a managed bean which is placed in the application scope. Also just do not declare the properties of a request or session scoped bean which is supposed to live as long as the bean itself as `static`.

It's under the hoods not different from the basic Servlet API.

Comment: @BalusC: In our application we are not storing any request or session scoped data in a managed bean which is placed in application scope.If two clients are using the application they are accessing the same session attribute. Can this be solved by using a custom scoped bean?

Comment: If two physically different clients have access to the same session variable then it's likely been stored as a `static` property of a session bean. Or it's just you who misinterpreted the "session" concept and incorrectly assumed that two different windows or tabs of the **same** browser instance represents a different session. If you want to test multiple clients, then you have to test using **physically different** machines or webbrowsers (e.g. Firefox and Chrome).

Comment: @BalusC: If the user opens two different client sites (which use the same application) http://app:7001/bank A and http://app:7001/bank B on the same webbrowser, both the clients have the same session id. How can they have a different session Id if opened in the same browser?

Comment: Are it two different contexts? By default, the session is not shared between different contexts. However, some servletcontainers can be configured to share the session between all deployed contexts. In Tomcat for example, if you set `emptySessionPath="true"` in `<Context>` for both WARs, then they will share the session. Again, this is **not** the default! But if it is basically the same context (and you oversimplified the URL example), then you need to ensure that you deploy it as two different contexts instead. So, just provide two WAR (or EAR) files.

Comment: @BalusC: One War file is deployed for all the clients. Our application is used by more than 2 clients.  So, is there a way to use only one War file for mulitple clients?

Comment: Then it was just a misinterpretation on your side of how the session works. You need to test with physically different webbrowsers (e.g. Firefox and Chrome), eventually on physically different machines.

Comment: Let me put the question this way, if the user opens Bank A site and bank B site in the same web browser then both will have the same session Id. Can this be solved by using only one War file?

Comment: Yes, it will then have the same session ID. It's then technically used by ONE client, not two! No, this cannot be solved using only one WAR file.

Answer (score 1):

JSF 2.0 helps you to provide a way to create user interfaces and has some built-in annotations for handle scopes like request, session or application. In simple scenarios use request, view, flash and session scope could work for you. But if you need something more elaborated take a look at [MyFaces Orchestra](http://myfaces.apache.org/orchestra/index.html) which provide the well known conversation scope (requires spring) or even better take a look at [MyFaces CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/index.html), which provide you things like bean validation, scripting, window scope, and much more!. Use CODI is the best for new JSF web applications, because follows the standard for CDI - JSR 299, and provide you some useful goodies.

The best way to start with CODI is look on [MyFaces CODI Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/EXTCDI/Index) and you can also ask question on [MyFaces Users and Dev Mailing lists](http://myfaces.apache.org/mail-lists.html).