# Support multiple client websites on the same application using JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem similar to 
[proof of concept for multiple clients in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482033/proof-of-concept-for-multiple-clients-in-jsf-2-0)

Our application is deployed as a single ear file within the ROOT context in Weblogic. However we need to support multiple client websites on the same application. The client name is appended in the URL e.g. http://myApp/client1/home.jsf , http://myApp/client2/home.jsf . 
There is absolutely no problem when the different URLs are accessed from different machine or even different browsers. However when accessed through different tabs in Firefox, they share the data from one application to the other because of the same JSession ID. Is there any way to use custom scoped beans that look at the client URL before creating the session beans.

Having multiple ear files for each application is not an option as we support 100+ client websites. :(

Answer (score 0):

Suitable scopes for this situation are conversation, request and view. Unsuitable scopes are session and (depending on your usage) application. Although CDI doesn't have a view scope, there are a number of 3rd party implementations you can use. (View scope is handy for ajax.)

Conversation scope acts like request scope until a conversation is explicity started. Until you end the conversation, it is tied to the view in which is was initiated, so you can have multiple instances of a conversation scoped bean, one per browser window.